# prove: $2^n$ is not divisible by 5 for any $n$

Tags: number-theory

there is a prove that there is no $2^n$ that is divisible by 5?

Comment: Since there will be no $5$ in prime factorization of $2^n$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a special case of the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic): every integer can be *uniquely* written as a product of primes. Since both 2 and 5 are primes, an identity like $2^n = 5k$ for $k\in \mathbb{N}$ would contradict the uniqueness of prime factorisation.

Exercise: more generally, find a necessary and sufficient criterion on integers $m$ and primes $p$ for $m^n$ to be divisible by $p$ for some $n$. Further prove that if divisibility holds for some $n$, then it holds for all natural $n>0$.

Comment: In fact something even more general holds: If $R$ is an [integral domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain) and $p,q \in R$ are non-associated [prime elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element#Divisibility.2C_prime_and_irreducible_elements) then $p \nmid q^n$ for all $n \geq 1$. The proof of course goes by induction on $n$ (I shall not write it here as that would essentially give a complete answer to the original question)

Comment: @Kahen: You don't need $\rm\:q\:$ prime, only that prime $\rm\:p\nmid q\:$. By definition, a prime divides a product iff it divides one of the factors.

Answer (score 7):

**HINT:** Use the fact that the powers of $2$ end with $2,4,8,6$ and for divisibility for 5 last digit has to end with either 5 or $0$.

Answer (score 5):

**HINT** $\ $ By [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14579/troubles-finding-inverse-modulus/14608#14608) for computing inverses modulo a prime $\rm\: 2\:n+1\:$ (here $5$) we have:

$\rm\quad\ \ \displaystyle \frac{1}2\ \equiv\ \frac{n+1}{2\:(n+1)}\ \equiv\ n+1\ \ (mod\:\ 2\:n+1)\:.\quad $ Hence $\rm\ 2^n \equiv 0\ $ times $\ (1/2)^n\ $ yields $\rm\ 1\equiv 0\ \Rightarrow\Leftarrow$

More generally any integer $\rm\:a\:$ coprime to $\rm\:d\:$ can be constructively inverted $\rm\:(mod\ d)\:$ by employing the [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to find a Bezout relation $\rm\ a\ b + c\ d = 1\ \Rightarrow\ a\ b \equiv 1\ \:(mod\ d)\:.$

This is very closely related to "rationalizing denominators", e.g. see my [sci.math post](http://groups.google.com/groups?selm=y8zwtid4b0u.fsf@nestle.csail.mit.edu) for further remarks on rationalizing denominators 
and computing inverses via (minimal) polynomials, the extended Euclidean 
algorithm, Grobner bases, resultants, norms, etc.

Comment: Or multiply both sides by $ 2^{-1} \equiv 3 \pmod{5} $.

Comment: That's equivalent: I use $\ 1/2 \equiv -2 \equiv 3$. The point of writing it out as above is that it explicitly shows how the inverse of $2$ arises from writing $1$ as a linear combination of $5$ and $2$, i.e. the fundamental Bezout linear representation of the gcd.

Comment: @Bill, your "since $x=5x-2(2x)$ may show that, but it is a completely obscure observation *unless you already know you need to make the inverse appear*. In that case, why no just multiply by $3$?

Comment: @Mariano: The point of writing it the way that I did was was to nudge  the OP to discover the relation between inverses and the Bezout relation. Not only is that not obscure, but it is a fundamentally sound way to teach - much better than handing answers to students on a silver platter. The joy of discovery goes a long way towards reinforcing true understanding.

Comment: But, Bill: there are *two* points to be made: first, that one needs to multiply by the inverse, second, that with enough ingenuity one can use the Bezout relation to find it. But "since $x=5x-2(2x)$" is only clear to someone who already understood both things, or a cryptic hint that one should understand them. I agree to disagree here with you, as we essentially always do in matters of pedagogy.

Comment: @Bill: In Scotland, there is at least one sheep, at least one side of which looks black! :)

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** [For every modulus, all relatively prime integers are a multiplicative group.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n)
(Without this, number theory would be quite pointless)