# determine with proof, all the positive integers $n$ for which $n$ is not the square of any integer and $[\sqrt{n}]^3$ divides $n^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

determine with proof, all the positive integers $n$ for which:

- $n$ is not the square of any integer and,
- $[\sqrt{n}]^3$ divides $n^2$. where $[x]$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.

**My Approach:**

Well I tried a few test cases and I concluded that no prime number greater than 4 holds true to this statement. Except that, I couldn't recognize a pattern or make a solution on my own so please help me out.

Comment: What about the primes $n=2$ and $3$?

Comment: the greatest integer function would evaluate $0$ right? then how would it be divisible

Comment: $[\sqrt{2}]=1$,  $[\sqrt{3}]=1$.

Comment: @ShlokJain, what cosmo5 said. I agree, though, that no prime $n\ge5$ will work.

Comment: okay I will edit that into the question

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\,[\sqrt n]\! =\! k < \sqrt n < k\!+\!1 \!\iff\! k^2 < n < (k\!+\!1)^2 \!\!\iff\! 0 < \overbrace{n\!-\!k^2}^{\color{#0a0}{\textstyle j}} \color{#0a0}{< 2k+1}$

Thus $\, k^3\mid (k^2\!+\!j)^2 \Rightarrow  k^2\mid j^2 \Rightarrow k\mid j\, $ [via Rational Root Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/25721/242), so cancelling $\,k^2$

yields $\ k\mid (k\!+\!j/k)^2 \Rightarrow \,\bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{\color{#c00}k\mid (j/k)^2\,\color{#c00}{\mid\, 4}}\ $ by $\,\color{#0a0}{j/k \le 2}$

Comment: Can You please explain the last line k∣(j/k)2∣4   by j/k≤2. How did you arrive k | 4?

Comment: I think I got it how it is. Since 0 < j < 2k + 1 , therefore we can write 0 < j/k <= 2. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Shashikant Yes,  $\,\color{#0a0}{j/k}\,$ is $\color{#c00}1\,$ or $\,\color{#c00}2\,$ so its square $\color{#c00}{{\rm divides}\ 4}\ \ $

Comment: But in case of when j/k = 1, k | 4 will not hold true?

Comment: @Shashikant Why?

Comment: I am not able to get this because I think if j/k = 1 and j = 1 and k | 4 then it implies that k = 1.

Comment: In that case (when k =1) n = 2, 3 will be the solution. Right?

Comment: @Sha Correct for $k=1$. There are only $6$ cases to check $\,k=1,2.4\,$ and $\,j = k,\,2k\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

Consider $k$ such that $k^2<n<(k+1)^2$. Then $\lfloor n\rfloor=k$ and $n=k^2+i$, $1\leq i\leq 2k$. We get the following:

$$k^3|(k^2+i)^2\Leftrightarrow k^3|k^4+i(2k^2+i)\Leftrightarrow k^3|i(2k^2+i)$$

#### $\text{If }k>1$

Consider a prime $p$ that divides $k$ and let $v_p(k)$ the exponent of $p$ in the factorisation of $k$. We must have $$v_p(k^3)\leq v_p(i(2k^2+i))\Leftrightarrow3\cdot v_p(k)\leq v_p(i)+v_p(2k^2+i)$$ Suppose $v_p(i)\leq v_p(k)$. Then, obivously, $v_p(2k^2+i)=v_p(i)$ so $v_p(i)+v_p(2k^2+i)\leq 2\cdot v_p(k)$, which would lead to $3\cdot v_p(k)\leq2\cdot v_p(k)$ which is a contradiction ($p$ divides $k$ so $v_p(k)\geq 1$).

Thus, for any $p $that divides $k$, $v_p(i)>v_p(k)$ so $k|i$ and $k\neq i$. However, $i\leq 2k$, so this implies $i=2k$ (so $n=k^2+2k$) which gives us $$k^3|2k(2k^2+2k)\Leftrightarrow k^3|4k^3+4k^2\Leftrightarrow k^3|4k^2 \Leftrightarrow k|4$$

Thus, just check cases $k=2,4$, which give $n=8,24$

#### $\text{If }k=1$

Then this gives us $n=2,3$ and again, just check those cases.

Comment: don't you think $n = 8$ would also work

Comment: @ShlokJain It's a bit easier to use the Rational Root Test - see my answer.