# ={∈ | 4|^2 }, ={∈ | 2| }. Prove =.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show (a) ⊆;     Show (b) ⊆.

a) Show A⊆B
Let y ∈ A,
Since 4 | y^2,
y^2 = 4m for some integer m
y = 2sqrt(m), so 2 | y,
which implies y ∈ B

b) Show B⊆A
Let x ∈ B, 
Since 2 | x, 
x = 2k for some integer k 
x^2 = (2k)^2 = 4k^2 = 4(k^2), so 4 | x
which implies x ∈ A

Hence, A = B.

Is my proof correct? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: More generally: [Show $\,a^n \mid b^n\Rightarrow a \mid b,\,$ i.e. $\,r\in \Bbb Q,\,r^n\in\Bbb Z\Rightarrow r\in\Bbb Z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25716/show-an-mid-bn-rightarrow-a-mid-b-i-e-r-in-bbb-q-rn-in-bbb-z)

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not correct. You can't deduce from $y=2\sqrt m$ that $2\mid y$, since $\sqrt m$ could be a non-integer.

If $4\mid y^2$, then $y$ is an even integer, because, if $y$ was odd, then $y=2k+1$ for some integer $k$, and then $y^2=4k^2+4k+1$, in which case $4\nmid y^2$.

Comment: From 4 | y^2, y^2 = 4m for some integer m, can I deduce that since every number in B is even, and y is even, x ∈ A and x ∈ B?

Comment: What is $x{}{}$?