# How can I prove prime factorization theorem by induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

The prime factorization including both existence and uniqueness. I have totally no idea about this problem except the basecase.

In this problem we only consider number greater or equal to 2. So the basecase should be n=2, and it is easy to prove. But for I.H, I have no idea, should I make I.H be n = ${p_1p_2...p_i}$ or sort of things?
Is there any hints for me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show the existence part, which is where the induction is used.  For this proof, it is easiest to use strong induction: you don't simply assume the case $n-1$ in order to prove $n$, but you assume all cases less than $n$.  Using this, the proof is rather simple:

The case $n=2$ is our base case, which is obvious.  Now let $n$ be any natural number greater than $2$, and assume for our induction hypothesis that a prime factorization exists for every $1<m<n$.  If $n$ is prime, then we're done.  Otherwise, $n=ab$ where $a,b>1$.  Use our induction hypothesis to complete the proof.

Comment: So uniqueness can't be proved by induction right?

Comment: I've not seen a proof of uniqueness using induction.  I've always seen it done using Euclid's Lemma (which is the underlying reason that there is uniqueness).  I'll look around to see if there is a proof that makes use of induction

Comment: I found here (http://www2.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/maths/research/notes/inductive_proof_of_fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic.pdf) a proof of uniqueness using induction.  It's not too hard to follow, so hopefully this helps on that front.

Comment: @SonicFancy See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/117416/242) and [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/403108/242) for a complete inductive proof based on ideas of Zermelo.