# Question on Tim Gowers's Unique Factorization Proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, euclidean-algorithm

In [Tim Gower's blog post: How to discover a proof of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2011/11/18/proving-the-fundamental-theorem-of-arithmetic/) he gives a proof of Euclid's Lemma using Lagrange's Theorem, but at the end he links to an [older post](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/%7Ewtg10/FTA.html) giving a "direct" proof based on descent steps of the Euclidean algorithm, but without invoking the algorithm. There,
in the "Proving the lemma $p|ab \implies p|a$ or $p|b$" section, Gowers considers counterexamples to Euclid's lemma.

> if $p$ divides ab without dividing either  or , how can one find any other example of a prime  dividing  without dividing  or ?

To create new examples, he suggests varying $a$ in two ways:

1. Let $a' = a+p$. Then $a'b=(a+p)b = ab + ap$, which is divisible by $p$ since $p$ divides both RHS terms. However $p \nmid a+p$ and $p \nmid b$, therefore we have a new counterexample to Euclid's lemma.
2. For some integer $h < b$ let $a' = ha$.

My question is why must $h$ be less than $b$? Gowers says...

> What happens if we replace $a$ by $ha$? Well, we know that $p$ divides $hab$,
> since it divides $ab$, but perhaps it divides $ha$. Of course, if $p $ does
> not divide $h$, then we suspect that $p $ will not divide $ha$ either, but
> that is what we are trying to prove. But hang on! **Our counterexample
> was supposed to be minimal, so as long as $h$ is smaller than $b$ we
> are all right.** **So we now have two methods of producing new examples:
> multiply by a number smaller than $b$, and add or subtract a multiple
> of $p$.** The question now is: can we use these two processes to construct
> a smaller example?

Why should $h < b$? What does he mean by "we are all right"?

Does he mean we need $hab > ab$ otherwise we violate the minimality of ? In that case, all we need is $h > 1$.

Does he mean we want $hab < ab$? I don't think that's what he is saying, but even still, in this case, all we need is $h < 1$.

Or does he mean that $ha$ is a new example by itself? In that case $h > b$ to not violate minimality of $ab$.

p.s thanks @BillDubuque and @joriki for checking over my question.

Comment: The claim appears to be that, if we choose $h<b$ and such that $p\nmid h$ then $p$ can not divide $ha$ since if it did $ha$ would be a smaller counterexample to Euclid than $ab$ is.

Comment: @lulu But that's not needed since when $a<p$ we can use the descent $a \to p\bmod a\,$ as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2973557/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque  Oh, agreed.  This seems a bit of a long way round the barn.

Comment: Yes, it's not clear why Gowers is doing that since it only obscures the (Euclidean) heart of the matter and needlessly complicates the proof.

Comment: The *key idea* (obscured by Gowers page) is:  the integers $x$ such that $\,p\mid xb$ are closed under subtraction, so closed under remainder (= iterated subtraction), so closed under gcd (= iterated remainders), so since they include $x=a$ and $x = p$ they also include $\,x=\gcd(a,p)\ $ [$=\color{#c00}1$ by $\,p\nmid a\,$], so $\,p\mid \color{#c00}1\cdot b.\,$ See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1216353/242) for elaboration. This will be greatly clarifed when one studies ideal theory (Euclidean $\Rightarrow$ PID).

Comment: Regarding possible ways to prove the *fundamental theorem of arithmetic*, in the paper of Pierre Samuel that I linked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1151530/242), he examines in detail approaches based on all possible permutations of a few fundamental theorems (including those mentioned above).

Comment: @BillDubuque  This [derivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4234646/80778) is the one Tim Growers's is writing about. I haven't yet studied how this relates to the version in your second comment.

Comment: That's a bit different. That method, interpreted *constructively* yields what I call *Gauss's algorithm* for computing modular inverses and fractions, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3059260/242). If we know that all $\,a\not\equiv 0\,$ are invertible $\!\bmod p\,$ then this implies Euclid's Lemma, by $\,a\not\equiv 0,\ ab\equiv 0\!\underset{\times\ a^{-1}}\Rightarrow\! b\equiv 0,\,$ so $\,p\nmid a,\,p\mid ab \Rightarrow p\mid b\ \ $