# Elementary demonstration; $p$ prime, $1 \lt a \lt p$, $\;1 \lt b \lt p \quad$ Then $ p\nmid a b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers

Update: If this question is of interest, you can also click [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3281320/432081).

---

Update: Using Bill Dubuque's [lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1216353/432081) and logic proving Euclid's lemma, we can supply an elementary proof.

To get a contradiction, assume than $p \mid a b$.

Let $S = \{n \in \Bbb N \, | \, p \mid nb \}$. Then $p \in S$ and $a \in S$. Moreover, $S$ is closed under subtraction.

Let $d = \text{min(}S\text{)}$. By the lemma, $d \mid p$, so $d = 1$ or $d = p$.

If $d = 1$, since $d \in S$, it must follow that $p \mid (1 \times b)$, which is absurd since $b \lt p$.

By the lemma, $d \mid a$, so if $d = p$ then $p \mid a$, which is absurd since $a \lt p$.

---

I've been motivated (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3234473/432081)) to prove the following result using only elementary techniques.

Let $p$ be a prime greater than $2$.

Let $1 \lt a \lt p$

Let $1 \lt b \lt p$

Then

$$\tag 1   p\nmid a b$$

I think that this is as simple as first showing that

$$ \text{For every integer n } \ge 1 \text{ such that }  p\nmid n, \; \;  p\nmid na$$

and ironing out some details.

> Using only the 'first page' of elementary theory of the natural numbers/integers (for example [Euclidean division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division), the construction of $\Bbb Z$, the existence of prime factorizations and that modular arithmetic is well-defined), can this approach work for proving $\text{(1)}$?

Besides answering yes in the comments, a proof would be appreciated (this elementary approach can be exhausting).

Comment: From the definition of prime number, I think it is easy to show that $p\mid ab\implies p\mid a\lor p\mid b$; so the contrapositive of this result will establish your desired result (EDIT: I guess proving the result I say here would take a bit more than the definition of primes). As far as your proposed approach goes, I think that it would be more work than needed.

Comment: I gave a couple direct proofs by induction in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1216213/242). But it's not clear what you mean by "no number theory", so it's not clear if they suffice. E

Comment: See also [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/117659/242) of Euclid's Lemma by inductively proving that a fraction writable with coprime denominators is an integer. There are many variants of these "direct" proofs but they all are essentially "assembly language" compilations of higher-level more conceptual proofs.

Comment: So, while at first glance they don't appear to "use number theory", that's only because the use has been highly obfuscated by eliminating all the higher-level concepts, e.g. directly inlining inductive proofs of gcd properties  by repeatedly subtracting, etc. I elaborate on this in the answers and their links.

Comment: And another way is to use [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3059260/242) to show that $a$ is invertible $\bmod p\,$ (and the inductive proof yields an algorithm to compute the inverse, essentially a special case of the (extended) Euclidean algorithm).

Comment: Thanks @BillDubuque for all the links and comments. I will review them and try to get out a proof. As for the amount of number theory, I thought it could all be developed ab initio. But of course you can always just state up front what you want to use as a starting point.

Comment: Re: your edit, all 4 proofs I linked seem to satisfy your "front page" criterion. But if you are interested in *mastering* number theory then you shouldn't seek these arithmetical assembly language versions. Rather, you should seek to understand their higher-level conceptual counterparts (which generalize to other number rings, e.g. Euclidean or gcd domains).  What is the reason you are interested in peeking at the assembly language?

Comment: @BillDubuque I'm imagining this work being fed to an $\text{AI MATH BOT}$ to see what it can do. I know, too much time on my hands. From elementary foundation wanted to also show $\quad$ $d \mid n$ and $n = ab$ then we can **tit-for-tat factor** $d$. $\quad$ $d = xy$ where $x \mid a$ and $y \mid b$. $\quad$ $\frac{a : b}{x : y}$

Comment: For that see [Euler's Four Number Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/611202/242) and related properties described there.

Comment: The proof you posted is just the contrapositive form of the proof I gave above the Lemma you linked to.

Comment: @bill yes. I know - almost copied your proof using the lemma. This question came up on my worksheets so it was the one I wanted answered. I am hoping to revisit https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3235873/432081 without relying on this. Just skating around Euclid's lemma for now...

Comment: Ok, wasn't sure if you realized that. It's not clear what you are aiming at.

Answer (score 1):

You need some more than the definition of prime to prove this. The reason is that in other rings (systems of 'numbers' [they can actually be numbers, polynomials or any 'thing' that you can sum and multiply] with sum and product) there are elements that can be only divided (essentially) by $1$ and themselves, but there are pairs of this 'numbers' $a,b$ such that $p\mid ab$ but $p$ does not divide $a$ or $b$. A well-known example is $2\cdot3=(\sqrt {-5}+1)(-\sqrt {-5}+1)$.

The best-trodden path for natural numbers is through Euclid's algorithm and Bezout's identity. It is not difficult to read, but kind of long to post here and easy to find.

Comment: I am not concerned with abstract ring theory. I am looking only at the natural numbers. I know about Euclid's algorithm and Bezout's identity but trying to logic-boot this up from less theory.

Answer (score 0):

If p divides ab, then it divides a or b (I'm not sure if you covered this; you can try to prove this as an exercise otherwise). This implies that it is less than or equal to a or b (since 1 is less than a and b), which contradicts the fact that a is less than p and b is less than p.

Comment: The end game is to prove Euclid's lemma from the arguments made here.

Answer (score 0):

Well,that's not true
Just take one counterexample p=7 (prime greater than 2)
Take a=3
b=4
3.4=12 which is not divisible by 7

Comment: If you look closely I had the vertical bar with the slash in it $p\nmid a b$, and not $ p \mid a b$

Comment: Oh I'm wrong,maybe I'm not focus haha

Comment: If like that, just using property of prime number is sufficient