# show that if $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$ then $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d} = \frac{a-c}{b-d}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d} = \frac{a-c}{b-d}$

Precalculus Mathematics in a nutshell says it's easy to verify by cross-multiplication but I'm having difficulty doing so.

(not a homework problem, any help would be appreciated)

Comment: this makes sense if $b\ne0, d\ne0, b\ne d$

Comment: moreover $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d} = \frac{k_1 a + k_2 c}{k_1 b + k_2 d}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\dfrac{a}{b} = \dfrac{c}{d} \Rightarrow ad = bc \Rightarrow ad -  cd = bc - cd \Rightarrow (a-c)d = (b-d)c \Rightarrow \dfrac{a-c}{b-d} = \dfrac{c}{d} = \dfrac{a}{b}$

Comment: perfect, thank you

Comment: Anybody knows if this theorem has a name ?

Answer (score 4):

Substituting $$a=bt,c=dt$$ then $$\frac{a-c}{b-d}=\frac{bt-dt}{b-d}=t$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Asserting that $\frac ab=\frac cd$ is equivalent to $ad=bc$. Now, use this equality to prove that $\frac{a-c}{b-d}=\frac ab$.

Comment: yeah, I spent an hour doing that last night. I will give it another stab

Comment: Haven't you just rephrased the question? How does it help?

Comment: @Zacky It helps **a lot** if the OP sees that $\frac{a-c}{b-d}=\frac ab\iff (a-c)b=(b-d)a$.

Comment: Well, assuming he spent an hour already, OP didn't see that, or something is unclear. In the question he mentioned about cross mutiplication, but couldn't do it.

Comment: thank you. I would have gotten from the hint. I did set up the cross multiplication but didn't equate it to a/b. thank you everyone

Comment: I suggest that you mark one of the answers as the accepted one.

Comment: i will. I'm studying them now

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac a b - \dfrac {a-c}{b-d} = \dfrac {a(b-d)-b(a-c)}{b(b-d)}=\dfrac{bc-ad}{b(b-d)}=\dfrac{c-a\dfrac d b }{b-d}=\dfrac{c-a\dfrac c a}{b-d}=0$

Comment: this assumes $d\ne b\ne0$

Answer (score 1):

Simply *subtract* the fraction's (defining) equations, i.e.

$$\begin{align}   b\,y &\,=\, a\\ d\,y &\,=\, c_{\phantom{|}}\\ \hline \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\Rightarrow\ \ (b\!-\!d)\,y &\,=\, a\!-\!c\end{align}\qquad$$

Said geometrically: subtraction preserves *same-slope* vectors (here points on the line $\,y \,=\, (a/b)\,x)$

**Remark** $ $ This [leads to](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/117659/242) a *vector* form of the Euclidean algorithm, and the descent step in a proof of Euclid's Lemma and the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic (essentially dating back to Euclid).

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\text{If }\qquad  \frac ab=\frac cd&=m\\
\text{then}\qquad\qquad a&=mb\\
c&=md\\
\therefore \frac {\lambda a+\mu c}{\lambda b+\mu d}
&=\frac{\lambda mb+\mu md}{\lambda b+\mu d}\\
&=\frac {m \big(\lambda b+\mu d\big)}{\lambda b+\mu d}\\
&=m\\
\end{align}$$