# Proving uniqueness of prime factorization using induction

Tags: induction, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove that factorization into primes is unique using mathematical induction. Here is my attempt and I would like to know if my reasoning is valid (and advice for any improvements if possible). Thank you.

Proof: Let $A(n)$ be the statement 'Natural number $n$ is unique in prime factorization.'

Initial step: case n = 1,2 is trivial.

Inductive step: Suppose $A(1), A(2), ... A(k)$ are all true for some $k$. If $k+1$ is a prime, it is unique. If $k+1$ is not a prime, it can be written as a product of two natural numbers both smaller than $k+1$, let's say $ k+1 = ab$. Since $a,b$ is both less than $k + 1,$ $A(a), A(b)$ is true so $a$ and $b$ can be written as a unique factorization of prime as follows: $a = p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}...p_i^{a_i}$ and  $b = q_1^{b_1}q_2^{b_2}...q_i^{b_i}$. So $k + 1 = ab = p_1^{a_1}q_1^{b_1}p_2^{a_2}q_2^{b_2}...p_i^{a_i}q_i^{b_i}.$ If $p_k = q_k$ then $p_k^{a_k}q_k^{b_k}$ can be written as $p_k^{a_k + b_k}$. Since $k + 1$ is in form $p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}...p_i^{e_i}$, base are unique since they are prime and exponents are unique since they are natural numbers. Therefore all natural numbers can be expressed in unique prime factors by induction.

Comment: How do you know that $k+1$ can't be written as $cd$ where $c,d$ have unique factorizations that use different primes than $a,b$ do?

Comment: @lulu I assumed using inductive step.

Comment: You can't.  The inductive hypothesis only applies to numbers $≤k$.

Comment: but isn't $k+1 > a$ and $k + 1 > b$?

Comment: So what?  You applied the hypothesis to $a,b$ but I say there's a different factorization $k+1=cd$ that has nothing to do with $a,b$.  You haven't said anything to prove me wrong.

Comment: I thought whatever $cd$ I choose, it's less then $k+1$ so it would all fit in inductive step.

Comment: It’s worth seeing how your proof fails when there is no unique factorization. Let $R$ be the ring of numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt{-5},$ where $a,b$ are integers, and with norm $a^2+5b^2.$ your proof works for $R,$ by induction on the norm, but $6=2\cdot 3=(1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5}).$

Comment: A good test for supposed proofs of unique factorization is to look at the Hilbert numbers.  These are just the integers of the form $4n+1$.  Note:  you can multiply two of these two get a third.  There are primes, i.e. Hilbert Numbers that can not be written as a non-trivial product of other Hilbert numbers.  Thus, $5$ is a prime but so is $21$ since neither $3$ nor $7$ are Hilbert numbers.  Your argument works in this context, but it shouldn't because unique factorization is false here.  $21, 209, 33$ and $133$ are all primes in this sense and $21\times 209=33\times 133$.

Comment: @lulu I am kind of new to formal math proof so sorry if I am asking too much... I tried to show that all natural number can be written in unique factors of prime. So I guess my proof is wrong but if it was correct should it also be true on the hilbert number system?

Comment: My point was that your logic applied to that case as well, and since the theorem is false in that case there must be a flaw in your logic.  But I have already said what the flaw is.  You start by declaring $k+1=ab$ and then you get to work on $a,b$ but if I started with $k+1=cd$ and got to work on $c,d$ there is no guarantee that we get to the same factorization.  I am afraid the problem is a lot harder than that.  A lot harder.

Comment: You should be aware that the proof of Unique Factorization that appears in Euclid is pretty much the proof we use today.  It's a brilliant argument and we haven't found a whole lot of ways to improve on it.  That said, there are "elementary" proofs using induction...a standard one can be found, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113869/how-can-we-prove-that-among-positive-integers-any-number-can-have-only-one-prime/117416#117416)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ingredient you're missing is that if $k+1=\prod_{i\in S}p_i^{A_i}=\prod_{j\in T}q_j^{B_j}$ then$$p_i|k+1=\prod_jq_j^{B_j}\implies\exists j\in T(p_1|q_j)$$where $\implies$ needs a proof by induction on $m:=\sum_jB_j$ of the fact that, if a product of $m$ integers is divisible by a prime $p$, at least one factor is. Hence if $k+1$ has multiple prime factorizations so does $(k+1)/p\le k$, contradicting the null hypothesis.

In case the proof of this theorem about $m$ products is unfamiliar, we proceed as follows:

- $m=1$ is trivial;
- We also include $m=2$ in the base case, proven below;
- If it works for $m=\ell$, a product of $\ell+1$ factors is a product of $2$ factors, the first $\ell$ & the last one, so $m=2$ completes the inductive step.

Soo $m=2$ is the hard part. If $p=uv$ but $p\nmid u$, there are integers $x,\,y$ with $xp+yu=1$ by [Bézout's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity). So $p|xpv+yuv=p$ (because $p|uv$).